# Can we install .exe file generated by a C# console app? if yes, how?

Tags: c#, installation, exe

Can we install .exe release file generated by a C# console app? if yes, how?

Comment: By **install** do you mean **deploy**?

Comment: By creating an installer with something like InstallShield, Wix, NSIS, Advanced installer, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. The generated exe file just runs the console application. If you want to create an installer, I suggest researching Wix.